# Chances of getting 3 in a row

Tags: java, probability

I'm trying to simulate a "3 sided dice" and the chances of getting the same number 3 times in a row. I believe the formula is this: (1/3)^3
I made the following in java to simulate this over many tries like this:

```
        win = (int) (Math.random() * 3);

        if (win != 1) {
            n=0;
        }
        if (win == 1) {
            n++;
        }
        if (n == 3) {
            n=0;
            l++;
        }

        y++;
```

So l will be the number of times the same result came up three times in a row. And y will be the total number of 'rolls'. However the result I get does not tend to (1/3)^3 over many tries. Is this because I am only counting 1's turning up in a row and not 1 OR 2 OR 3 turning up 3 times in a row? Or what is the mistake here. Thanks

Comment: The chance is `(1/3)^(3-1)` Consider if you have one dice, the chance of 1 in a row is 100%.

Comment: Why (1/3)^3?  If you enumerate all the possible outcomes, what fraction do you see?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. What Im really trying to work out is if I roll a 3-sided dice and always bet on 2, then what is the average number of rolls needed to get three 2's in a row?

Answer (score 1):

The code is very unclear as to what it is doing.  I suggest restructuring it like this

```
Random rand = new Random();
int attempts = 10000;
int allSame = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
    int a = rand.nextInt(3);
    int b = rand.nextInt(3);
    int c = rand.nextInt(3);
    if (a == b && b == c)
        allSame++;
}
System.out.println("The ratio was " + (double) allSame / attempts);
```

Using Java 8

```
IntSupplier dice = () -> rand.nextInt(3);
int allSame = IntStream.range(0, attempts)
                        .map(i -> dice.get())
                        .filter(d -> d == dice.get() && d == dice.get())
                        .count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you tried in your code, but your statement that it should be `(1/3)^3` isn't correct.

**It has to be `(1/3)^2`, as said by Peter Lawrey in the comments:**

1. The first dice can be any number 0-2.
2. The second dice must be the same number, which has a propability of `1/3`.
3. The third dice also has the propability `1/3`.
4. This leads to the formula `1/3 * 1/3` = `1/9`

**You get the same result if you think this way:**

1. If you roll the dice three times, you get 27 different possibilities
   (`3^3`).
2. Three of these possibilities have the desires result (`0-0-0`,
   `1-1-1`, `2-2-2`).
3. Your propability is therefore `3/27` = `1/9`

**You code is really confusing, so I suggest writing it different:**

```
int lastNumber[2];
int winCount = 0;   

for(n = 0; n< 1000; ++n){

    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    if(num == lastNumber[0] && lastNumber[0] == lastNumber[1] && n > 2){
        ++winCount;
    } 
    lastNumber[0] = lastNumber[1];
    lastNumber[1] = num;
}
system.println("Propability = " + (winCount*100)/1000.0f);
```

Note, however, that the winCount is increased twice if you dice is the same 4 times in a row. (Use `num=4;` if you don't want that behaviour)